# How to deserialize a specific item subset of a class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have this class to deserialize my classes:

```
public class Serializer <T> {
       public T SerializeAppPath(string xmlpath) {
           T apppath;
           using (TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(xmlpath)) {
               XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
               apppath = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(txtReader);
               return apppath;
           }
       }
}
```

Here is the class which I want to deserialize the XML into:

```
   [XmlRoot("KPIPATHS")]
    public sealed class KpiPath
    {
        public sealed class KPI
        {
            [XmlElement("Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("RequestTemplateFullPath")]
            public string RequestTemplateFullPath { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("RequestFullPath")]
            public string RequestFullPath { get; set; }

            public KPI()
            {
            }
        }

        [XmlArray("KPIS")]
        public List<KPI> Kpis { get; set; }

        public KpiPath()
        {
        }
    }
```

Below is how I am executing it to get result from XML. I am retreiving list of "Kpis" and my problem is I would like to take from it only one `KPI` set based on condition `"when Name = something"` then I would like to use and pass that `KpiPath` class further. Hope you get my point.

```
Serializer<KpiPath> serializer2 = new Serializer<KpiPath>();
kpiPath = serializer2.SerializeAppPath(KpiPaths);
```

Some example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<KPIPATHS>
<KPIS>
    <KPI>
      <Name>AXD</Name>
      <RequestTemplateFullPath>D:\something</RequestTemplateFullPath>
      <RequestFullPath>D:\something</RequestFullPath>
      <ResultFullPath>D:\something</ResultFullPath>
    </KPI>
    <KPI>
      <Name>DRE</Name>
      <RequestTemplateFullPath>D:\something</RequestTemplateFullPath>
      <RequestFullPath>D:\something</RequestFullPath>
      <ResultFullPath>D:\something</ResultFullPath>
    </KPI>
</KPIS>
```

Comment: Can you please include some example XML?

Comment: You can manually parse `xml` (bad) or you could just deserialize everything (whole `KPIPATHS`) and perform conditional filtering later.

Comment: no i would like to avoid xml reader or something like that. Serialization way is what i choosed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `XmlSerializer` will always deserialize / serialize everything that it can on the given type.  You are trying to conditionally query an XML document which is a different function. XmlSerialization should NOT be used as a query into XML but should take the entirety of a given type and serialize it completely *to* XML or deserialize a new instance of the given type *from* XML.  Additionally, only one XmlRoot attribute can be defined in a given serialization chain.

From MSDN:

> There are two attributes that can be applied to a class (and only a
>   class): XmlRootAttribute and XmlTypeAttribute. These attributes are
>   very similar. The XmlRootAttribute can be applied to only one class:
>   the class that, when serialized, represents the XML document's opening
>   and closing element—in other words, the root element. The
>   XmlTypeAttribute, on the other hand, can be applied to any class,
>   including the root class.

See here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx

In short, you want to have a different node be the XML root during serialization, which is not supported.

---

In your situation, I would add a function in your `KpiPath` class to query the data in your type instance once it has been completely deseriailzed (since functions and methods are not serializable) similar to this:

```
void Main() {
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KpiPath));
    KpiPath newPath = new KpiPath();

    newPath.Kpis.Add(new KPI() {Name = "test", RequestTemplateFullPath = @"C:\test", RequestFullPath = @"C:\test"});
    newPath.Kpis.Add(new KPI() {Name = "test", RequestTemplateFullPath = @"C:\newTest", RequestFullPath = @"C:\newTest"});
    newPath.Kpis.Add(new KPI() {Name = "anotherTest", RequestTemplateFullPath = @"C:\funTest", RequestFullPath = @"C:\funTest"});
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using(StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb)) {
        ser.Serialize(writer, newPath);
    } // end using
    Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

    List<KPI> matches = newPath.KPIFromName("test");

    //For debugging, make sure we get two results (matching the two named test above), print a failure message if not.
    Debug.Assert(matches.Count == 2, "Invalid Count");

}

[XmlRoot("KPIPATHS"), Serializable()]
public sealed class KpiPath {

    [XmlArray("KPIS")]
    public List<KPI> Kpis { get; set; }

    public KpiPath() {
        Kpis = new List<KPI>();
    } // end default constructor

    public List<KPI> KPIFromName(string kpiName) {
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kpiName)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("kpiName", "No name provided.");
        } // end if
        List<KPI> matches = new List<KPI>();
        if(this.Kpis.Any()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < this.Kpis.Count; i++) {
                if(this.Kpis[i].Name.ToUpperInvariant() == kpiName.ToUpperInvariant()) {
                    matches.Add(this.Kpis[i]);
                } // end if
            } // end for loop
        } // end if

        return matches;
    } // end function GetFromName

} // end class KpiPath

[Serializable()]
public sealed class KPI {

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("RequestTemplateFullPath")]
    public string RequestTemplateFullPath { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("RequestFullPath")]
    public string RequestFullPath { get; set; }

    public KPI() {
    } // end default constructor

} // end class KPI
```

This way, you have an easy way to retrieve the items with the names you're interested in, and you don't have to have any complex / hard to follow deserialization logic.

If this is not a good solution for you, I would recommend going the route of using an `XmlReader` / `XmlDocument` combo to read specific items from your document based on XPath ([XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)) syntax.

Here are some related topics that address this issue:

- [partial xml serialization/deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030969/partial-xml-serialization-deserialization)
- [Serializing/deserializing partial XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593963/serializing-deserializing-partial-xml-files)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6exf3h2k(v=vs.110).aspx <-- When / how to use serialization types

Comment: Hi xDaevax, i putted your method inside KpiPath class and i tried to call it from other class like this:  List<KPI> ff =  kpiPath.KPIFromName(kpiname.ToString()); but its not working because type or namespace KPI could not be found ?

Comment: @Bob This is likely because you have declared your `KPI` class within the `KpiPath` class (which you don't have to do, and is possibly unwanted since you declared the class as public).  Try moving the `KPI` class outside of the `KpiPath` class.

Comment: i cannot because then my deserializer would stop to work then

Comment: @Bob, the KPI class doesn't need to be nested inside of the KpiPath class for it to work, it can be anywhere in your code as long as you have the Kpis property in KpiPath and the KPI class is public.

Comment: so you propose to split those classes i mean take KPI class to other file and then use the code?

Comment: @Bob, yes, or the same file, just outside of the KpiPath class.

Comment: it works right now i will give you as recolved just one more question could you modyfi your code i mean this linq i would like avoid linq if this would be simple to convert please.

Comment: @Bob  I have updated my answer as you requested and added a complete code listing.  Though I must ask, why do you want to avoid using lambda expressions?